# Handle Mouse Right Button Double Click for Shape

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, shapes, double-click

How I can handle the `Mouse Right Button Double Click` event for a [`Shape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're wrong, absolutely! Read my question please.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The shape class provides some events, I want to know how to use this events to simulate the MouseRightButtonDoubleClick, or if exists a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for a way to detect a double click on a Shape? In this case you should check the [ClickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.clickcount) property of the [MouseRightButtonDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouserightbuttondown) event. This property provides the number of times an element was clicked. The sample on the documentation page checks for single, double and triple clicks:

```
private void OnMouseDownClickCount(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Checks the number of clicks.
    if (e.ClickCount == 1)
    {
        // Single Click occurred.
        lblClickCount.Content = "Single Click";
    }
    if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        // Double Click occurred.
        lblClickCount.Content = "Double Click";
    }
    if (e.ClickCount >= 3)
    {
        // Triple Click occurred.
        lblClickCount.Content = "Triple Click";
    }
}
```